# What does passing one qubit that is entangled with another through a CNOT gate do?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

I am watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7b4J2INq9c) in which a programming language for quantum computing is introduced. There is code like  this:

```
// Inside TeleportClassicalMessage function
let msg = register[0]; // Initialized to |0⟩ state
let there = register[1]; // Initialized to |0⟩ state

// Inside Teleport function
let here = register[0]; // Initialized to |0⟩ state
H(here); // here is now |+⟩
CNOT(here, there); // 'here' and 'there' are now entangled as the Bell state

CNOT(msg, here); // What does this do?
```

For those of you not familiar with coding, what it seems to be doing is feeding $|+⟩$ (control) and $|0⟩$ (target) to a CNOT gate, which creates the entangled Bell state. Then it takes the first qubit out of that state, `here` (without examining it), and feeds $|0⟩$ and `here` to a CNOT gate again.

What exactly does this do?

Comment: are you sure `msg` is initialised to $\lvert0\rangle$? Because if it is, then the second CNOT is not active and does nothing

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this is the code used in the video: https://github.com/Microsoft/Quantum/blob/master/Samples/Teleportation/TeleportationSample.qs

In the TeleportClassicalMessage function (from which Teleport is called), msg is conditionally inverted (depending on the outside argument).

Note the [line](https://github.com/Microsoft/Quantum/blob/master/Samples/Teleportation/TeleportationSample.qs#L98):

```
if(message) { X(msg); }
```

which does the conditional flipping.

Inside Teleport function, the second CNOT will flip `here` if the original message was 1. It would also mean changing the state of `there` because it's entangled with `here`. In case the original message was 0, the state of `there` will be unchanged.